# How to get index from template inside prime-ng carousel in Angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, primeng

I have used below code to show data uploaded from excel inside template tag using prime-ng carousel in angular 2.

**exceldata.html:-**

```
<p-carousel headerText="Category" [value]="ExcelRowDatas" class="pcaro">
   <template ngFor let-ExcelRowData [ngForOf]="ExcelRowDatas" let-i="index" pTemplate="item">
       <div class="ui-grid ui-grid-responsive">
          <div class="ui-grid-row">
             <div class="ui-grid-col-6">Index No.</div>
             <div class="ui-grid-col-6">({{i}})</div>
          </div>
          <div class="ui-grid-row">
             <div class="ui-grid-col-6">Place</div>
             <div class="ui-grid-col-6">{{ExcelRowData['Place']}}</div>
          </div>           
       </div>
   </template>
</p-carousel>
```

**exceldata.ts:-**

```
let ExcelRowDatas = [{"Place": "New York"}, {"Place": "London"}, {"Place": "Paris" }]
```

**Plunker:-**  https://plnkr.co/edit/PUOlAQ7abbAJ7el4ciQ2?p=preview

I could not able to get index of the row inside template tag inside ng-carousel. But I was able to get index inside template without using ng-carousel. How can I get the index value inside ng-carousel with template?

Comment: You are using PrimeNG which is a collection of rich UI components for Angular, but you tagged your question with Primefaces tag which is a popular open source framework for JavaServer Faces. Please correct the tagging and read tag descriptions before posting to Stackoverflow. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`p-carousel` doesn't have an options to use your template variables on carousel element. That works with `ngFor` directive because `ngFor` directive add(template as is) or remove provided template from DOM based on collection provided to it.

But the way `p-carousel` works is, it pass `templateRef` as parameter to `Component` & component take care of binding that `templateRef` to particular.

Let's dig deeper to understand what it is, as you wrote `template` inside `p-carousel` you have to right `pTemplate="item"` directive on it. So that `p-carousel` collects all pass template which has `pTemplate="item"` by [this line](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/carousel/carousel.ts#L105-L117) of code, and it appends those all template to below snippet `ngFor`, where `itemTemplate` is template passed by us & `value` is `ExcelRowDatas`.

```
<li *ngFor="let item of value" class="ui-carousel-item ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <ng-template [pTemplateWrapper]="itemTemplate" [item]="item"></ng-template>
</li>
```

That is the reason why even if we pass value as template variable, those values gets ignored. Short answer is you can't pass/use custom template variable to `p-carousel` template.

---

There could be several solution to solve this problem. If you're only interested in `index` of element. You can add new property `index` inside your `ExcelRowDatas` manually

```
this.ExcelRowDatas.forEach(
  (item, index) => item.index = index + 1
)
```

Then you could directly use that value on template `{{item.index}}`

[**Demo Here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/fPEVmYGjHYX2e8ydu4ey?p=preview)

---

If you need selected page value in outer component, then put event on `(onPage)` over `p-carousel`, it will get called every time you change carousel select dropdown.

```
<p-carousel [value]="jsonStr" class="pcaro" (onPage)="setPage($event)">
  <ng-template ngFor let-json [ngForOf]="jsonStr" let-i="index" pTemplate="item">
    ...
  </ng-template>
</p-carousel>
```

**Code**

```
page: any;
setPage(page){
    this.page = page;
}
```

[**Preview**](https://plnkr.co/edit/O7idkLAk6Hlyu2cWyL7G?p=preview)

> **Note:** Consider using `ng-template` instead of `template`, template has been deprecated since Angular 4.

Comment: As of now, I am using Angular 2. That is why I didn't use ng-template. Thank you for your response. Good work. Keep it up.

Comment: @RGS Thanks, just curious, what way you finalized? and did you understand above explanation(sorry for my poor english :p)?

Comment: I will go with index forEach workaround. Demo you have attached under index workaround is older one i.e., my original plunker demo given in my question. Yes. I understood.